# Como puedo solucionar este error que me da la transacción?: "La solicitud COMMIT TRANSACTION no tiene la correspondiente BEGIN TRANSACTION"

Tags: sql-server

Hice una transacción con lo que se describe en el texto, pero al momento de ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error:

La solicitud

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

No tiene la correspondiente

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

Crea una transacción donde realices 3 inserciones a la tabla productos, marques un savepoint y después elimines uno de los productos insertados.
Añade rollback y commit a la transacción

```
begin tran

insert into productos values('manzana','A006')
insert into productos values('piedra','A007')
insert into productos values('monitor','A008')
save tran test
begin
delete from productos where  nombre like '%manzana%'
    rollback
end
    commit
```

Comment: ¿estás haciendo un `rollback` y luego un `commit`?

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente script se ejecutan los siguientes pasos:

1. Se inicializa la transacción con `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.
2. Se insertan los tres registros en la tabla de productos. *Se pueden ejecutar tres `INSERT` como lo tienes o simplemente se pasan los tres registros en una sola sentencia `INSERT`*.
3. Se muestran los resultados después de guardar.
4. Se crea un `savepoint` con el nombre **test**.
5. Se elimina la manzana de la tabla. *Ojo, que con `LIKE` se eliminarían todos los registros que contengan la palabra manzana independiente del que texto que tengan antes o despues de ella*.
6. Se muestran los resultados después de eliminar la manzana.
7. Se hace `ROLLBACK` para revertir la eliminación del registro de la manzana
8. Se utiliza `COMMIT` para que los cambios sean permanentes. *Ojo, no se puede retroceder después de la confirmación*.
9. Se muestran los resultados después de hacer los cambios permanentes.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO productos VALUES
('manzana','A006'),
('piedra','A007'),
('monitor','A008')
SELECT * FROM productos 
SAVE TRANSACTION test
DELETE FROM productos WHERE nombre = 'manzana'
SELECT * FROM productos 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION test
COMMIT TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM productos
```

Puedes encontrar mas información al respecto [en este enlace](https://www.sqlshack.com/transactions-in-sql-server-for-beginners/)